# When mounted in Enzyme, why does a ReCharts chart with a ResponsiveContainer not render the child elements of the chart?

Tags: javascript, enzyme, recharts

Given that I have a chart using React and Recharts like so:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="99%" height="99%">
  <LineChart data={data}>
    <Line dataKey="test"/>
  </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Why does mounting it in Enzyme with JsDom not render the children of the `LineChart` (ie the `Line` is not mounted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing a responsive ReCharts component for a web page, passing a string to the `width` or `height` prop of `ResponsiveChart` is valid and will render in the HTML markup. However, the chart component beneath (whether `LineChart` or any other chart) requires a specific integer width. If it recieves a string it will fail [a width/height validation](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/0d03d942112000a1d08146f667438fb74fa81913/src/util/ReactUtils.ts#L114) and [return null](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/chart/generateCategoricalChart.tsx#L1524) instead of rendering.

Presumably `ResponsiveChart` is responsible for sending the correct width/height props to it's children responsively. But for whatever reason it doesn't do this when mounted (perhaps because some feature of `window` isn't being emulated by JsDom) so it sends the strings instead, which causes the chart to not render it's children, without returning or logging any error message.

To fix that add a valid integer value for width & height:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width={700} height={300}>
  <LineChart data={data}>
    <Line dataKey="test"/>
  </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

In my case I added a prop to keep the string as a default but allow an override in the test context, ie: `width={this.props.width || "99%"}`.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer; it's exactly what was happening to me -- and since recharts fails silently, it's a bear to figure out. Thanks, @Jansky